# WordPress admin area has overlapping panels when resized

Tags: css, wordpress, browser, admin

Hay, not sure how many of you have come across this, but i was in a meeting with a client who has a small monitor and when i viewed the WordPress admin area, panels with overlapping.

This problem appears when the window gets resized. I've attached a screenshot of the issue

[image: Admin area issues]

Does anyone know a solution, or perhaps a CSS hack for this?

Comment: What do you want it to do instead?

Comment: I don't want it to overlap, i would prefer the browser to resize rather than push the boxes over each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the buttons that are causing the issue.

add:

```
#content_toolbar1 * {
    float: left;
}
```

That'll do the trick:

[image]

to your style sheet.

Comment: Latest version, swap over to the Visual view.

Comment: Looks like it's the buttons that are causeing the problem. I'll edit my answer.